# SQl Stuff not returning results

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have stored procedure which has below Sql query.

```
    SELECT  @WorkGrpIDforUser = STUFF((SELECT ',' +  convert (nvarchar(20),Work_grp_id )
      FROM WORK_GRP_USER 
     where emp_id in(@WorkTypeIdentity)
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
       ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
      ,1,1,'')
```

I am passing (@WorkTypeIdentity) values as 'ABC','HI' from my application. This query not returning any results. But If i put value 'ABC','HI'  in this query, it is giving results.

I am not getting what i am missing.Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: What's the difference between values you mentioned "values as 'ABC','HI' from my application" and "But If i put value 'ABC','HI' in this"?

Comment: I try to execute SP. If i pass value as 'ABC','HI' it is not returning results. But If i replce (@WorkTypeIdentity) by 'ABC','HI' in the query , it is working.

Comment: `STUFF` has nothing to do with the problem - your problem is that SQL Server doesn't take a single string parameter that you've passed it and decide to, instead of treating it as a single string, inspect the *contents* of the string, decide that it should split the string apart into *multiple* strings and then pretend that that's what you provided it. I can't think of any programming language that *does* act like you imagine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is nothing to do with `STUFF`. You cannot parameterise the `IN` clause in this way. What you end up running is something like:

```
emp_id in(''ABC', 'HI'')
```

i.e. you still are only checking `emp_id` for a single value. You have a number of options, the first (and preferable) is to use [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The first step in this is to create your type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfString AS TABLE (Value VARCHAR(MAX));
```

Then you can pass this type as a parameter:

```
DECLARE @Values dbo.ListOfString;
INSERT @Values VALUES ('HI'), ('ABC');
...
WHERE emp_id IN (SELECT Value FROM @Values)
```

Or pass to your procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProcedure @Strings dbo.ListOfString READONLY
AS
BEGIN    
    ....
END
```

The next option is to use `LIKE`:

```
WHERE   ',' + @WorkTypeIdentity + ',' LIKE '%,' + emp_id + ',%';
```

Finally, you can use some other string splitting method to split your parameter before comparison. For further reading on this I suggest you read:

- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)

To summarise these articles, either use a CLR string splitting function, or table valued parameters, should you create a string splitting function, your SQL Will be something like:

```
WHERE emp_id IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.Split(@WorkTypeIdentity))
```